# I am getting "io is not defined" error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using this on the client

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com:8440/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

When the server is too busy, sometimes it gives an "io not defined" error on the client. How can I resolve this ?

Here is my server code

```
var db_helper = require("./db.js");
var io=require('socket.io').listen(8440);
var check = require('validator').check,
    sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;
var roomid=0;
var anonid;
var ilet;
var userip;
var blck_id;

  io.set('transports', [

  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'websocket'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
```

The server has 16 GB RAM and 13.6 GHz CPU.

Comment: That's one fast processor!

Comment: Can you explain, what you mean with 'when the server is too busy'?

Comment: @dc5 ahh sorry :) cpu 13.6 ghz :)

Comment: @KornP I want to say more active users

Comment: Is it temporary? Does your server work properly after active users reduce. Or you continue to get that issue. What does the node server print/log when this happens.

Comment: Yes after users reduce,server works properly

Comment: Could you also provide the code for `db_helper.onlineusers` and anything it calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out,

get the clientside socketio library and put it in the folder from where the js files are served. Point the script location to this file location.

You will find the client side script here

```
 <server node_modules>\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\dist\socket.io.js
```

In the first place, as pointed by @Timothy try to find out why the node is getting busy.

Comment: I'll try this.But I don't know how can I find out why the node is getting busy

Comment: I pasted to my first message

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind node.js apps run in a single thread unless you're using something like Cluster to run more. This means that if you're doing something that blocks, it's possible for the requests to http://domain.com:8440/socket.io/socket.io.js to timeout, which would cause your io not defined error. You should see a 404 error in your console logs as well if / when this happens.

Comment: Where can I find log files ?

Comment: He is probably refering to firebug's log or chrome's. Same place where you see the error you about io undefined.

Comment: @Dslayer I looked js file is not serving.

Comment: If that problem is intermittent, it might be the blocking issue I mentioned in the answer above. If it's *not* intermittent then the problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to serve the socket.io.js file from a regular web server, as Chandu pointed out.
This should at least offload the node.js server from that load.

Secondly - and this is more important - look at what is blocking your node.js server. As node.js is single threaded, you should by all means avoid long-running operations.
Can you give an example of the code you are running in node?